# Is a group defined by its generator set and relations?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

I'm learning about generators from Dummit and Foote. They call this a presentation of the dihedral group:

$$D_{2n} = \left< r,s\,|\, r^n=s^2=1,\, rs=sr^{-1}\right>$$

Does this type of "presentation" determine/define a group? I think there are several groups that fulfill the above relations, e.g. the trivial group with $r=s=1$. An exercise is to determine the order of a group given such a "presentation". Is there some assumption I'm missing? Could someone clear this up for me?

Comment: The key point you are missing is that the stated relations are the **only** relations that the generators satisfy.

Comment: You assume this to be the minimal set of relations.

Comment: For that exercise, you can use [_Todd-Coxeter Al._](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd%E2%80%93Coxeter_algorithm) to find the orders of some certain finite groups. It really works!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The idea of presentation is that the elements of the group are allowed to have the listed properties, properties that follow from them, **and no other properties**.

So, the trivial group does satisfy the above relations, but it also satisfies the relation $s=1$, a relation that does not follow from the above relations, meaning it is *not* the group represented in this particular case.

---

More technically, what you wrote down as a definition of $D_{2n}$ is in fact a shortened notation, meaning that $D_{2n}$ is isomorphic to $G/H$ where $G$ is a **free group with 2 generators** and $H$ is the normal subgroup generated by all elements of the type $s^2$, $r^ns^{-2}$ and $rsrs^{-1}$ (i.e., all elements that are equal to $1$ in $D_{2n}$)

Using this, you can show that any group that satisfies the listed properties is **a quotient** of the generated group. If it satisfies only the listed properties, it is the whole group, if it satisfies some other properties (like $s=1$, it is a proper quotient (and, of course, the trivial group is a proper quotient of $D_{2n}$)

Comment: @Anna I added a more strict definition as well.

Comment: In the last paragraph you want “quotient”, not subgroup.

Comment: Hello. May I ask what "a proper quotient of a group" means exactly in the last paragraph? Does it mean being isomorphic to a quotient of the group by a proper subgroup? Then how the trivial group is a proper quotient?

Comment: @ssu By proper quotient of $G$, I mean it is isomorphic to $G/H$ where $H$ is not the trivial subgroup. Thus, the trivial group is a proper quotient because it is isomorphic to $G/G$.

Comment: Thank you. So you mean like, if they satisfy some additional property $R$, then the group generated would be $D_{2n}/<R>$, a proper quotient of $D_{2n}$?

Comment: @ssu Precisely so, yes.

Comment: Sorry, still a bit confused. What additional properties would the generators have to satisfy in order for $<R>$ to be the whole $D_{2n}$?

Comment: If they satisfy the properties $s=1$ **and** $r=1$, then $H$, the normal subgroup of $G$ (which is a free group with two generators), is equal to $G$. And therefore, $G/H$ is the trivial group.